# A few questions about Kudu Console in App Services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

App services can be deployed on several VMs. I would like to know:

- On which VM the Kudu Console is connected ? is it a shared drive for all the VMs associated with my app?
- If we modify a file in this console, does it impact all the VM of the app?
- About the log files, do they aggregate all the logs for all the VM ? or do they reflect only one VM ?

Thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To a specific instance, check this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2016/11/21/azure-app-service-how-to-connect-to-the-kudu-site-of-a-specific-instance/
2. I believe the storage is shared
3. Kudu pulls logs from the storage (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Diagnostic-Log-Stream) so probably application wide

You can take a look at the project [source code](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) to answer your questions.

This is probably what you want to examine: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/tree/master/Kudu.Services/Diagnostics